# How much caffeine intake a day is still safe for health?

Tags: caffeine, sleep-deprivation, coffee, drug-tolerance, safety

My question is: how much mg of caffeine (as found for example in Nescafe) consumed per day is still considered safe for health?

When taken in excessive amounts what can be the harmful effects?

Are there any harmful effects of sleep deprivation which is a likely result when caffeine is taken in large doses?

Is there any chance of developing any tolerance so that as days of use increase more caffeine is required to get the desired effect?

Comment: The title of your question is on topic here, but the entire rest of your question is off topic because it's about you. It's a request for personal medical advice. Can you edit it to ask only the question asked in the title?

Comment: @CareyGregory done editing the question

Comment: Retracted close vote, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an article published in November 2017 that states:

"*Evidence supported consumption of ≤400 mg/day in adults is not associated with overt, adverse effects.*"

Link to the article: 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278691517301709

You can see the meaning of 400 mg of caffeine at this webpage:

https://www.foodinsight.org/caffeine-safe-amount-daily-efsa

What makes 400 mg of caffeine?

1. 5 shots (2-oz) of espresso
2. 4.7 cups (8-oz) of drip coffee
3. 5 cans (250 ml) of energy drinks

Comment: Good answer but doesn't address all my questions

Comment: A guess is that the roof is lower than 400mg in long term consumption of caffeine. I have read about figures as low as 10mg a day. Personal experience has thought me that 150mg is absolute tops. However, the limit is probably higher in big people, than small.